# Google MAP API, Determine if a route passes by a polygon

Tags: google-maps

I have a map that shows 3 polygons and a route that passes a cross them. Each polygone has a title property. I would like to display a polygone title when the route passes by it.

This is the code I did :

```
<!doctype html><html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<title>Loading / Editing Zones</title>
<style>
     #map, html, body {        padding: 0;        margin: 0;        height: 100%;      }      #panel {        width: 200px;        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;        font-size: 13px;        float: right;        margin: 10px;      }      #delete-button {        margin-top: 5px;      }      #login_close{     display: none;    }   .labels {      color: red;         background-color: white;        font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;      font-size: 10px;        font-weight: bold;      text-align: center;         width: 65px;            border: 2px solid black;        white-space: nowrap;         }   .autocomplete-suggestions { border: 1px solid #999; background: #FFF; overflow: auto; }     .autocomplete-suggestion { padding: 2px 5px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; }   .autocomplete-selected { background: #F0F0F0; }     .autocomplete-suggestions strong { font-weight: normal; color: #3399FF; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=drawing,geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(),
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(),
  polys    = new Array(),
  map      = null,
  zoom     = 10,
  myPolygons = 
  [
    {
        "name": "zone1",
        "coordinates": [
            "51.44459,-0.21835",
            "51.46256,-0.11261",
            "51.43004,0.03708",
            "51.40777,-0.09888",
            "51.39064,-0.21149",
            "51.40692,-0.27191"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "zone2",
        "coordinates": [
            "51.56683,-0.22934",
            "51.54292,-0.13046",
            "51.57195,0",
            "51.59755,-0.03708",
            "51.5984,-0.13733",
            "51.59755,-0.19913"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "zone3",
        "coordinates": [
            "51.66148,-0.13733",
            "51.61461,-0.08514",
            "51.61887,0.02197",
            "51.65381,0.05905",
            "51.64359,-0.04807"
        ]
    }
];

  function drawPolygon(poly, polyLabel) {
    var options = { 
      paths: poly,
      strokeColor: '#AA2143',
      strokeOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: "#FF6600",
      fillOpacity: 0.7,
      polyTitle: polyLabel    
    };
      newPoly = new google.maps.Polygon(options);
      newPoly.setMap(map);
      polys.push(newPoly);
  }
  function sendPolygonForDrawing() {
    for(var i =0; i<myPolygons.length; i++){
        poly = new Array();
        var coord = myPolygons[i].coordinates;
        var lng = coord.length;
        for(var j=0; j<lng; j++){
            var longit_Latid = coord[j].split(',');
            poly.push(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(longit_Latid[0]), parseFloat(longit_Latid[1])));
        }
        drawPolygon(poly, myPolygons[i].name);      
        poly.pop();
    }   
  }
  //Route
  function calcRoute() {
      var start = "Croydon";
      var end = "Cheshunt";
      var waypts = [];
      var waysArray = ["London"];
      for (var i = 0; i < waysArray.length; i++) {
          waypts.push({
              location:waysArray[i],
              stopover:true});
      }
      var request = {
          origin: start,
          destination: end,
          waypoints: waypts,
          optimizeWaypoints: true,
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            var routCoordinates = fncRouteZoneIntersection(response);//this function populates the routCoordinates with the JSON data of the route.
            var exist = new Array();
            for(var i=0; i<polys.length; i++){//polys holds all polygons objects.
              for(var j=0; j<routCoordinates.length; j++){
                if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(new google.maps.LatLng(routCoordinates[j].k, routCoordinates[j].A), polys[i]) == true){
                    exist .push(polys.polyTitle);
                    break;
                    /*this breaks the loop checking when a point is found inside a polygon 
                    and go check the next one, because knowing that one point of the route is 
                    inside a polygon is enough*/
                }
              }
            }
        console.log(exist);
        alert(exist);
        }
      });
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map); 
    }
    function fncRouteZoneIntersection(response){
        var myRoute = response.routes[0].legs[0];
        var lngLatCordinates = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.steps.length; i++) {
            lngLatCordinates.push(myRoute.steps[i].start_point);
        }
        return lngLatCordinates;
    }

  $(function() {
    //Basic
    var cartodbMapOptions = {
      zoom: zoom,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.465872, -0.065918),
      disableDefaultUI: false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    // Init the map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),cartodbMapOptions);
    sendPolygonForDrawing();
    calcRoute();

    var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
      drawingControl: false,
      polygonOptions: {
        fillColor: '#0099FF',
        fillOpacity: 0.7,
        strokeColor: '#AA2143',
        strokeWeight: 2,
        clickable: true,
        zIndex: 1,
        editable: true
      }
    });
  });


</script>
<div id="map">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sounds like my code starting from the line : `var routCoordinates = fncRouteZoneIntersection(response);`............ is only checking the starting, waypoint and the end of the route against the polygons and not all the route points that is why I get an empty array when doing the check.

Can any one help me please?

Comment: You are checking only `myRoute.steps[i].start_point` points and none of them is inside your polygon. You can see that if you create marker for each point inside `fncRouteZoneIntersection()`  function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `overview_path` instead of route legs. See docs *overview_path contains an array of LatLngs that represent an approximate (smoothed) path of the resulting directions.*

```
function fncRouteZoneIntersection(response) {
    console.log('fncRouteZoneIntersection...');

//    var myRoute = response.routes[0].legs[0];
    var myRoute = response.routes[0].overview_path;
    var lngLatCordinates = new Array();
//    for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.steps.length; i++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.length; i++) {

//        lngLatCordinates.push(myRoute.steps[i].start_point);
        lngLatCordinates.push(myRoute[i]);
    }
    // console.log(lngLatCordinates);
    return lngLatCordinates;
}
```

and you have to change:

```
exist.push(polys.polyTitle);
```

to

```
exist.push(polys[i].polyTitle);
```

See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lupoy/1/edit) with markers. List of polygon titles is written to console.log.